# Estimating the number of birds in a specific area

Tags: estimation, methodology, ecology

I want to count the birds in an area. What's the proper statistical method for it? What are the good references for this topic?

Comment: A good start could be googling "linear transect", "point transect" and "capture-recapture". This book is an excellent reference: http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Distance-Sampling-Estimating-Populations/dp/0198509278

Answer (score 3):

You are probably better off asking this in a zoological (ornithological) forum. One reference that is statistical as well as ecological is

[http://www.amazon.com/Ecological-Methodology-Edition-Charles-Krebs/dp/0321021738](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321021738)